# Register Area and Controllers Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've a modular web application and I need to load some libraries on runtime, those libraries will contain `Controllers`.

Each controller must have a single `Area` and it's common to all controllers inside that library.

[image: Example1]

I've used ASP.NET Core's application parts to load this assembly during runtime.

```
services.AddMvcCore(setup =>
{
    setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());

    // Get all global filters
    foreach (var filter in GetInterfacesFromAssembly<IGlobalAsyncFilter>())
        setup.Filters.Add(new AsyncActionFilterProxy(filter, container));
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest)
.AddFormatterMappings()
.AddJsonFormatters()
.AddCors()
.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
     .Build();
})
.AddApplicationPart(GetModuleAssemblies());
```

`GetModuleAssemblies` gets all the possible libraries called in runtime that may contain `Controllers`

```
/// <summary>
/// Get any DLL that contains "ModularPortal.Modules.*.dll"
/// </summary>
private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetModuleAssemblies()
{
    string location = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("ModularPortal.Module*.dll");
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        yield return Assembly.Load(file.Name.Replace(".dll", ""));
}
```

Using this, the following controller is located in `/api/example1/test`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class Example1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    readonly IMembership membership;

    public Example1Controller(
            IMembership membership
        )
    {
        this.membership = membership;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return Ok("t1");
    }
}
```

The problem is that by adding `ApplicationPart` I'll need to use the `AreaAttribute` to identity that the controller belongs to `/Area`.

I want a generic "Module Configurator" that any controller inside that library WILL have a common area.

I started by creating an interface to identity the module:

```
public interface IModule
{
    string DisplayName { get; }
    string RouteName { get; }

    void Configure(ModuleConfiguration config);
}
```

Then inside the library, I used it:

```
public class Module : IModule
{
    public string DisplayName => "Example Module";

    public string RouteName => "Ex";

    public void Configure(ModuleConfiguration config)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I want to use this code to configure everything about that module, including Area and controller registration.

In the example above, after registering an Area the path should be `/api/ex1/example1/test`.

This will only be possible if I, somehow, changed the `AddApplicationPart` to register it myself.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you are trying build modular project like I was. Here is the reference [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109475/Modular-Web-Application-with-ASP-NET-Core) for you.

Hope it help, if you have any query please let me know. I would love to support.

Comment: It seems the right way but there isn't anything about `area`

Comment: I'm not sure about the area you want but my app can separate like [this](https://i.imgur.com/CWTupZE.png) You can take a look at my open source project [here](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core) for reference

Comment: I'm talking about MVC's Areas, which allows you to put Controllers and Views inside the same route like the provided example `/api/ex1/example1/test`, here `ex1` represents the area

Comment: I get it then my project can help you achieve that. This application use [GruntFile.js](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/Gruntfile.js) to copy all of dll from another project that live outside mvc app.